# Is RESTlet suitable for this job?

Tags: rest, client-server, restlet

(sorry for reposting this question, for some reason I can't log in to the other account)

Is RESTlet the best choice for performing the following server/client architecture?

1- we have a server containing a database and an ftp server (within a network of 20 clients)

2- the various users on the network can create user accounts (there exists different access permissions)

3- users should be able to:

(a) retrieve data from the database or files from the ftp server

(b) store data in the database or upload files to the ftp server

This is not a web application that requires a UI, the thing is that multiple programs (with UI) will be developed on the clients computers and these programs should interact with the API in order to do points (a) and (b) as accessing the data on the server and displaying them on the UI of these programs.

I made a research so far, but would like to get more expert opinion from you. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is perfectly doable with Restlet. Actually, you can use any technology to implement your web API resources: databases, files, FTP sites, pure logic, etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am currently trying to read the tutorials on the restlet website, but since I am a beginner in web services, I'm finding some difficulty in understanding, do you have links for ebooks about restlet which could specify more basic steps ?

Comment: Jerome is coauthoring Manning's Restlet in Action (http://www.manning.com/louvel/), which is nearing completion.  You can buy the book through the Manning Early Access Program and be able to read the drafts until you take delivery of the ebook or paper book.  This is a good introduction to Restlet.